# How to read space-separated integers representing the array's elements and sum them up in C

Tags: c

How to read space-separated integers representing the array's elements and sum them up in C?
I used the below code but it reads all the elements in a new line:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int i = 0, N, sum = 0, ar[i];
    scanf("%d" , &N);
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &ar[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        sum = sum + ar[i];
    }
    printf("%d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: initially array is declared of size 0,

Comment: Just Do Not Select Any  Answer Best Answer  in short time , wait for it , Also Ask In Question About what is use of zero sized array , it will help you get better answer.

Comment: @VemuriPavan: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 5):

Your array `ar` is defined with a size of `0`: the code invokes undefined behavior if the user enters a non zero number for the number of items.

Furthermore, you should check the return value of `scanf()`: if the user enters something not recognized as a number, your program will invoke undefined behavior instead of failing gracefully.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i, N, sum;

    if (scanf("%d", &N) != 1 || N <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid number\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int ar[N];
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &ar[i]) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid or missing number for entry %d\n", i);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        sum += ar[i];
    }
    printf("%d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the program will still fail for a sufficiently large value of `N` as there is no standard way to check if you are allocating too much data with automatic storage.  It will invoke undefined behavior (aka *stack overflow*).

You should allocate the array with `malloc()` to avoid this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int i, N, sum;
    int *ar;

    if (scanf("%d", &N) != 1 || N <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid number\n");
        return 1;
    }
    ar = malloc(sizeof(*ar) * N);
    if (ar == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate array for %d items\n", N);
        return 1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &ar[i]) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid or missing number for entry %d\n", i);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        sum += ar[i];
    }
    printf("%d\n", sum);
    free(ar);
    return 0;
}
```

Finally, there is still a possibility for undefined behavior if the sum of the numbers exceeds the range of type `int`.  Very few programmers care to detect such errors, but it can be done this way:

```
    #include <limits.h>

    ...

    sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if ((sum >= 0 && arr[i] > INT_MAX - sum)
        ||  (sum <  0 && arr[i] < INT_MIN - sum)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "integer overflow for entry %d\n", i);
            return 1;
        }
        sum += ar[i];
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i=0,N,sum=0;
    scanf("%d" ,&N);
    int ar[N];
    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
        scanf("%d",&ar[i]);
    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
        sum=sum+ar[i];
    printf("%d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

This should be the code.
You have initially declared the array of size `0` (because `i=0`).

Even though you declared the array of size `0`, when I ran it on my machine, it actually executed successfully with the correct output.

This is generally due to undefined behavior which means that we can only guess the output when the code is correct. If the code has undefined behavior, then it can do whatever it wants (and in the worst case the code will execute successfully giving the impression that it's actually correct).

Declaring a Variable Size Array (VLA) is optional in C11 standard. Thus, it depends on the implementation of the compiler whether it will support VLA or not. As pointed out by [@DavidBowling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6879826/david-bowling) in comments, if the compiler does support, then **declaring a VLA of size 0 can invoke undefined behavior** (which you should avoid in all cases). If it doesn't support, then this will simply give a compilation error and you'll have to declare the array size as some integer constant (example, `int arr[100];`).

Comment: It is worth pointing out that declaring a VLA of size 0 is undefined behavior in C.

Comment: @DavidBowling Yeah, I was thinking that too, because I ran OP's code in my machine and it actually executed fine. It must be undefined behavior.

Comment: You were correct to point out that OP declared the array to be of size 0 instead of size `N`. This leads to undefined behavior since the array access goes out of bounds. I was just mentioning that even the _declaration_ of the VLA invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @DavidBowling Searching the net, I found out now that VLA's were allowed in C99 standard but was moved to "optional features" in C11 standard.

Comment: @DavidBowling If the feature is optional now, I guess it depends on the implementation of the compiler whether this is UB or not?

Comment: It is optional whether a C11 compiler implements VLAs or not, but it seems that the most common ones do. It is not optional for C99. The declaration `int ar[i]` in OPs code _was_ a VLA, since `i` is not an integer constant. If the compiler supports VLAs, this is undefined behavior for `i = 0`; if not, this is a syntax error and will not compile.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int i=0,N,sum=0;
scanf("%d" ,&N);

int ar[N];

for(i=0; i<N; i++)
{
scanf("%d",&ar[i]);
}
for(i=0; i<N; i++)
{
sum=sum+ar[i];
}
printf("%d\n", sum);
return 0;
}
```

You should declare the array after accepting the value of N.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i=0,N,sum=0;
    scanf("%d" ,&N);

    int ar[N];

    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&ar[i]);
        sum=sum+ar[i];
    }
    printf("%d\n", sum);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior if the user fails to enter valid numbers.

Comment: yeah i know, i just tried to correct the code of #Vemuri Pawan.

Answer (score 1):

As this is a very simple question I'll expand it a bit to include some good programming practices.

#### 1. Analyze the problem

We have to complete two tasks here:

1. Read and store the numbers to array.
2. Sum the array elements.

Of course you can both read and calculate the same time, but we ❤ the [SoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) design principle. This will help you later with bigger programs.

#### 2. Create the program structure

In this state we have to consider what function to use, as we already solved the data structure problem (we use array).

*Of course, we always can put the whole procedure in `main` function but this would  break the [SoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) principle.*

The main principle here is:

> I create a [function](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_functions.htm) for a separate procedure.

So we'll have to build two functions. Let's consider the following example:

`ReadArrayData` will be used to read the data from the standard input (your keyboard in other words) to array. But what will declare as parameters? We surely have to pass the **array** and the **array size**. The return type of this function will be `void` (we don't have to return something).

*Keep in mind that if you pass array to function you can manipulate it as you please and keep these changes in your main program. This is because the arrays are passed always by reference to a function.*

In the end this will be your function prototype:

```
void ReadArrayData(int arraySize, int array[]);
```

`CalculateArraySum` will be used to calculate the sum of the array elements. The function prototype will be the same as for  `ReadArrayData` with the difference that the returning type will be `int` (we return the sum).

```
int CalculateArraySum(int arraySize, int array[]);
```

#### 3. Write your program

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ReadArrayData(int arraySize, int array[]);
int CalculateArraySum(int arraySize, int array[]);

int main(void) {
  int N;
  printf("Give the array size: ");
  scanf("%d", &N);

  int array[N];

  ReadArrayData(N, array);
  int sumOfArrayElements = CalculateArraySum(N, array);

  printf("The sum of array elements is %d.\n", sumOfArrayElements);

  return 0;
}

void ReadArrayData(int arraySize, int array[]) {
  printf("Give %d elements: ", arraySize);
  for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i) {
    scanf("%d", &array[i]);
  }
}

int CalculateArraySum(int arraySize, int array[]) {
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i) {
    sum += array[i];
  }

  return sum;
}
```

I know this was a large scaled answer, but I saw you are new to computer programing. I just wanted to present you the main functionality to solve all kinds of problems. This was just a small introduction. In the end, you have to remember what steps we take to solve a problem. With time and as you solve many problems you will learn many many other things.